# How do I extract some data from a file of some data to use as args of a command

Tags: shell, scripting

I have a file of 5 lines, and 2 columns.
It contains Nodename and its respective IP address.

Each line looks like this:

```
Node1 10.10.10.1
```

I am to create nodes in load balancer using a script.
<del>I need 1st row column 1 to map with 1st row column 2.</del>

Command to create a node in a Load balancer is as below

```
tmsh create /ltm node Nodename address IP_address
```

Comment: This question is not clear. What are you trying to do? What is the input? What is the output?

Comment: When you say "I need 1st row column 1 to map with 1st row column 2." are you saying "each row is a record, containing 2 fields" (If so then you have already said this, if not then what?)

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
while read -r node ip; do
  tmsh create /ltm node "$node" address  "$ip"
done < input.txt
```

Comment: @msp9011 Thanks a lot. It's working partially. I'll try to add more on it. Thanks a lot once again.